# Single Linked List: Null Pointer Exception when searching through list with while loop

Tags: list, while-loop, nullpointerexception, linked-list, nodes

Im having trouble with this method im trying to get to work. My assignment is to delete the first occurance of an element. It works fine when there is a element to delete in the list. But if i search for an element that is not in the list, it throws me a nullpointer exception on my while loop. 
Cant seem to find the problem, i want the loop to stop after: either found element or when temp.next == null(aka at the end of the list).
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
public void deleteFirstOccurance(int data)      
{
    Node temp = head;
    boolean foundElement = false;

    if(head==null)                              //Sjekker om listen inneholder elementer
    {
        System.out.println("There are no elements in list");

    }
    else
    {
        if(temp.element==data) //Sjekker første node
        {
            head = temp.next;
            System.out.println(temp.element+" is deleted");
            elementCount--;
            foundElement = true;
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp.next != null || temp.next.element != data)   //Leter fra node sin next frem til den finner data eller treffer null
            {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            if(temp.next.element == data)
            {
                System.out.println(temp.next.element+" is deleted");
                temp.next= temp.next.next;
                elementCount--;
                foundElement = true;
            }

        }
    }
    if(!foundElement)
        System.out.println("No elements found");
}//Oppgave3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown, because you are getting the value of `temp.next.element` before checking if `temp.next` is `null`.

The same thing after `while` loop finishes: you have `if (temp.next.element == data)` but `temp.next` may be `null` here. At this point it is either the next element is the one you are looking for, or `null`. So a check `if (temp.next != null)` should suffice.

Also the condition should have `&&`, not `||`: you want to *continue* the loop, while you have a next element *and* this element is not what you are looking for.

So to fix the issues, replace `while(temp.next.element != data || temp.next != null)` with `while (temp.next != null && temp.next.element != data)`, and replace `if (temp.next.element == data)` after the `while` loop with `if (temp.next != null)`

Comment: I thought that could be a problem, but still getting the nullpointer when searching for an element that doesnt exist.

Comment: I was using the  ||  in the loop since it can jump out at anytime as long as it has found the element or the temp.next  == null. I only need the first occurance of the element, no need to search more if it is found.

Comment: @AndréHatlo-Johansen See my edit. Also && will jump out in two cases: the element is found, or there is no next element. But || will jump out *only* if there is no next element and this element is the one you are looking for. That means || will never jump out.

Comment: Ofcourse... i had it the wrong way around. The if test fixed it all! Thank you so much